# How to move a curve without evaluating it in Sverchok?

Tags: sverchok

I obviously can't use matrix apply or move nodes, because curve before evaluation isn't defined by positions of vertexes (I think it's represented as a function). I tried curve offset and cast curve, but all those are distorting the curve, not just moving it.

Edit: I am using a "Curve Mapper" to create the curve. I tried changing clipping (min Y to -1 and max Y to 0), but it doesn't let me edit the curve (all points can be only moved to Y = 0).

I am stuck, why isn't there any "Move Curve" node? From my limited perspective, it renders a lot of other nodes useless (e.g. "Concat Curve" - I want to move one curve bellow the other curve and then do the join, otherwise it results in nonsense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *Apply Vector Field to Curve* node. Pass a vector or a matrix to it's *Field* input.

[image]

Comment: I don't seem to have [available](https://i.ibb.co/djw0sky/2020-11-20-13-59.png) the "Apply **Vector** Field to Curve". I tried "Apply Field to Curve" and that [works](https://i.ibb.co/ky2pdZW/2020-11-20-14-01.png) (I am probably horribly misusing some of the nodes). Thank you :). Edit: oh, you are right, passing just ordinary Vector works as well ^^.

Answer (score 0):

Initially pipeline was designed to create curve from mesh. When defining curve you can move it.
Is it possible?
Or you operate on some curves from beginning?

Comment: Unfortunately I was using "Curve Mapper" as a curve generator and that node doesn't seem to support moving its curve (setting negative Y limit causes the node to stop allowing for any nodes except those having Y = 0). Curve Mapper was easy to use, but it doesn't seem to be a great/universal way of generating curves (e.g. no loops allowed).